# Switching quickly between different C styles in emacs

Tags: emacs

What is the best way to define multiple different C-styles in emacs and easily? I have one project that requires the Google C/C++ style while everything else uses BSD. What I would like to have is a key combination to allow me to quickly change between the style provided by

https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-c-style.el

and the standard "bsd" emacs style.

Comment: See also [this question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2/different-indentation-styles-for-different-projects).

Comment: BTW, would the key combination `C-c .` be quick enough for you? It asks you for the name of the style you want to use for the current buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a key combination, I would suggest using [directory-local variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html). This modified example from the documentation should work:

```
((c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD"))))
```

Put this into a file called `.dir-locals.el` in the root of your project, and adjust the value for `c-file-style` as necessary.